# is there a way that i can access a url on button click without opening the website in android?

Tags: java, android, html

for example i have made a Nodemcu server and there are 3 links on the main webpage(192.168.18.100).
the thing i want to try is that when i click an android button this link get accessed without opening any new activity i.e i want to stay on the main activity.
this is my code so far that works but not according to what i want it.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button on = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    Button off =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Button pink = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

    on.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://192.168.18.100/ir?code=16236607"); // missing 'http://' will cause crashed
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND, uri);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    off.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://192.168.18.100/ir?code=16203967"); // missing 'http://' will cause crashed
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    pink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://192.168.18.100/ir?code=16214167"); // missing 'http://' will cause crashed
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can try to implement a WebView on your MainActivity. When you click on any of your button, load the WebView with your desired url.

You can find the way to implement WebView in this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview)

Comment: i dont want to show anything to the user i just want to access a link without showing it for example when the link is triggered or accessed using a browser it turns on the led in my home

Comment: It possibly a duplicate from [How to execute URL in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29458365/how-to-execute-url-in-android) or [Hit a URL without opening browser in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294863/hit-a-url-without-opening-browser-in-android-studio)